# Using Spring configuration to instanciate a service several times with different dependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-context

Hello Stackoverflowers (Spring is coming, better bloom  )

While trying to make my application modular, I encountered a lot of problem which I can't get my head arround.

Let's say that I have my domain which is already implemented and this domain is requiring some dependencies to be provided.

What I'm trying to achieve is having this domain (and its services) to be instanciated several times but with different dependencies.

I declared a configuration class for my domain.

```
class MyDomainConfig {

    @Bean
    fun doSomethingcommandHandler(
        eventBus: EventBus,
        commandBus: CommandBus,
        useCase: UseCase<DoSomething>,
        someRepo: SomeRepository
    ): CommandHandler<DoSomething> {
        return CommandHandler(eventBus, commandBus, useCase, DoSomething::class.java, someRepo)
    }

    @Bean
    fun doSomethingElseCommandHandler(
    eventBus: EventBus,
    commandBus: CommandBus,
    useCase: UseCase<DoSomethingElse>,
    someRepo: SomeRepository
    ): CommandHandler<DoSomethingElse> {
        return CommandHandler(eventBus, commandBus, useCase, DoSomethingElse::class.java, someRepo)
    }

}
```

Basically, the required dependencies should always be provided. I would have seen this configuration class as a skeleton or prototype for their instanciation.
Note that I did not declare the Configuration class as a configuration. This is because I thought about using it as an importable class in my actual configuration.

Now I created dedicated configuration which I thought would instanciate my domain with the provided dependencies.

Like so

```
@Configuration
@Import(
    MyDomainConfig::class,
)
class OfflineConfig {

    @Bean
    fun eventBus(): EventBus {
        return InMemoryEventBus()
    }

    @Bean
    fun commandBus(): CommandBus {
        return InMemoryCommandBus()
    }

}


@Configuration
@Import(
    MyDomainConfig::class,
)
class OnlineConfig {

    @Bean
    fun eventBus(): EventBus {
        return OnlineEventBus()
    }

    @Bean
    fun commandBus(): CommandBus {
        return OnlineCommandBus()
    }

}
```

It obviously does not work as I expected. 
Spring complains because it sees 2 beans eventBus. I get why, but I can't figure out a way of achieving what I want.
Here is the error:

```
The bean 'eventBus', defined in class path resource [com/demo/app/online/OnlineConfig.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [com/demo/app/offline/OfflineConfig.class] and overriding is disabled.
```

Profiles are not an options as I actually need both Configuration to generate an up an running domain with a given set of dependencies.

How would you instanciate services of the domain several time with different dependencies and make those available for application layer ? Or having one isolated contexts per declared configuration ?

I also tried Modulith and having different runner but I still encounter bean instanciations issues.

Thanks

Comment: Note that sprring already has an event bus - maybe you might want to use that. That being said, can you please share the exact error⚡️/stack traceℹ️ Spring blows up  with? Are you using the `EventBus` bean anywhere?

Comment: EventBus is an interface that my domain is relying on. It could be a Guava, Reactive or whatever. I need my domain to be agnostic from Spring.

As far as the error is concen, I'll add it in the question :)

Comment: It looks like you havre two `EventBus` implementations - How should you/Spring decide which one to use? For the error, try renaming one of the `eventBus()` methods.

Comment: It's not clear why there needs to be multiple __available__ implementations at the same time - how would `MyDomainConfig` know which implementation to use?  Besides using a different name (like @dan1stiscrying mentioned), consider looking into the `@Conditional*` annotations..

Comment: I also thought about conditional beans but the sentence _Profiles are not an options as I actually need both Configuration to generate an up an running domain with a given set of dependencies._ made me unsure.

Comment: My target is to instanciate my domain several times to cover different use case which are actually related to the dependencies used. 
I would have expect a qualifier to help me tell, for instance from a controller « hey here is the commandBus instance used for OnlineExecution ». And then would have the whole context of OnlineExecution of my domain being used. 
It’s almost like I’ve different apps but using the same domain. Eventbus only have one implementation in my case but the instance must be different from on contexte to the other

Comment: Not an outlandish request imo. Spring does this all over the place. I.e. @EnableJpaRepository, for example you have to specify the package to enable so I can have 2 JpaRepositories and 2 sets of associated beans and it all works.. But that's the same point others have made. You need SOME mechanism to decide which one to use. Either by naming convention (which Spring also does) or perhaps with some kind of facade. I'm using a facade to implement read/write replicas ... so its pretty much the same thing except read/write replaced with online/offline.